# Truncate - unexpected result with sanitize(RedCloth.new(object))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, truncate, sanitize, redcloth

I have some text that I would like to output using RedCloth. I am trying to figure out how this works and I can't get the result that I would like.

**Used Code:**

```
truncate(sanitize(RedCloth.new("*some* interesting text")).to_html, length: 6)
```

**Result:**

*some*

**Expected Result:**

**some** i...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized what the problem was. I did not pay attention to my code. I need to reverse truncate with sanitize :) Wops!

```
sanitize(truncate(RedCloth.new("*some* interesting text").to_html, length: 6, separator: " "))
```

This gives me the result that I needed. You have to use separator: " " as well to make it look clean.

Comment: Could you mark your own answer as 'accepted', if it is solved? It helps, when browsing ruby-related questions in search of unresolved cases :)